# Showing which register is being used to record

Tags: vim

Pressing <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>[letter]</kbd> will make Vim start recording keystrokes in the register `[letter]`. While Vim is recording it will show the *recording* message. I'd like to see something like *recoding in 'e'*, to help me remember which register I did select.

Is there a way to make Vim show also in which register it is recording?

*PS: I learned to use <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> to avoid remembering which register I selected, but having some confirmation from Vim would be helpful.*

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. You would have to override the `q` command that starts (and stops) recording, query the register yourself, and store it somewhere, e.g. in a global variable that you could include in a custom `'statusline'`.

It's just a few lines of Vimscript, but I'd argue you don't need this (at least once you're more proficient with Vim). Just make it a habit to record into certain registers (I personally start with `q`, then `w`, and rarely have used more than two macros at once.) Same with yanking and marks.

After recording is finished, you can always refresh your memory (if you recognize the commands) via

```
:reg
```